# How can I fix the problem so that I can push to heroku masterbranch?

Tags: heroku

I tried to push to heroku masterbranch, but my gem file seems to have an issue and it did not want to install it.
The message I am getting is:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/rails-watch-list-93.git'

I tried some of the solutions that i found here- those did not work.. Can someone help me?

Comment: *Git* has nothing to do with your problem. Git relays your commits to Heroku. Heroku inspects and either accepts or rejects your commits, sending the result (and error messages if rejecting) to Git, which relays this to you. Read *all* the error outputs from Heroku carefully as the reason Heroku rejected your commits will be listed.

Comment: That last line of output is the _least_ helpful. Please [edit] in all contiguous error and warning lines that appear above it.